# Flutter build on Android and iOS just started giving error: Failed to load providerinstaller module

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

My flutter app build for Android and iOS was working when I last built it on Jan.29, 2021, I upgraded to Android Studio 4.1.2 now when it attempts to connect to Firebase:

```
runZoned(() {
runApp(App());
  }, onError: FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError);
```

I get the warning:

> Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

And the main.dart file randomly opens and the cursor is moves to:

```
runApp(App());
```

Both the iOS and the Android versions are producing this error and it just started today on the same code base that was previously working, both on a physical Android device (Pixel 4), physical iOS device and on the Android emulator running the latest version of Android.

**Update:**
This is a known issue with Android Studio open issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5231

Comment: is your app going through any startup crashes, when the app tries to connect?

Comment: If it doesn't crash on startup, and it compiles successfully, then there is no issue with the codebase or the flutter framework. It sounds like it's a connection issue you will have to check on the firebase project's console page. Double check your firebase's google-service.json file and GoogleService-Info.plist file, and check there is no configuration issue

Comment: check that your client id is correct, and everything is setup per the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios

Comment: There is no crash on startup up and the code compiles. I’m even able to use fire base services like auth and fire store. Nothing has changed in my fire base configuration. I’ll try to update my fire base libraries.

Comment: @DanGerchcovich I've updated to the latest firebase libraries, but I'm still getting the same error. As mentioned, my app compiles and I can access firebase services, but the error persists and is distracting since my IDE (Android Studio) opens the class where I initialize firebase everytime I recompile my project.

Comment: can you try through another IDE, perhaps visual studio code?

Comment: just to test it

Comment: it could be just an Android Studio issue

Comment: @DanGerchcovich Thanks, it turns out to be an IDE issue. The error message is unrelated. Details on this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5231